# Need help on configuring Nginx ingress controller for hcloud-cloud-controller-manager

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to follow [this suggestion](https://github.com/hetznercloud/hcloud-cloud-controller-manager/issues/74#issuecomment-678073133) to use [Hetzner load balancer](https://github.com/hetznercloud/hcloud-cloud-controller-manager/blob/master/docs/load_balancers.md) as a Nginx ingress controller.

`helm install ingress-nginx` with these configurations:

```
controller:
  config:
    use-proxy-protocol: "true"
  replicaCount: 3
  service:
    type: LoadBalancer
    annotations:
      load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/name: nginx-controller-new
      load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/location: hel1
      load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/use-private-ip: true
      load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/algorithm-type: least_connections
      load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/uses-proxyprotocol: true
      load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/hostname: somehost.com
```

Deployments:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo1
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: echo1
          image: hashicorp/http-echo
          args:
            - "-text=echo1"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5678
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: echo1
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5678
  ipFamilyPolicy: PreferDualStack

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: echo-service
                port:
                  number: 80
      host: somehost.com
```

After installation, a Hetzner load balancer is successfully provisioned, however, it isn't able to detect the services:

[image]

I'm at a loss here. How can I connect the echo1 app to the ingress-nginx-controller service? I check out [all of the available helm values](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml) but I cannot find something like `service.selector` to target echo1's service and make it publicly available. Can someone help me? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

I am not the Kubernetes master (more a noob) but I got it working with a L4-loadbalancer.

An annotation has to be set to your Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

And to use it without nginx-ingress, that worked for me (not tested with your labels)

```yaml
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: "nginx-hello-world"
  labels:
    app: "hello-world"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "hello-world"
  strategy:
    type: "Recreate"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "hello-world"
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: "rancher/hello-world"
          name: "nginx-hello-world"
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: "http"
```

**Service**
for HTTP (to test your deployment)

```yaml
---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "nginx-hello-world"
  labels:
    app: "hello-world"
  annotations:
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/name: lb-development
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/hostname: somehost.com
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/protocol:   http
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/health-check-port: 10254
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: "hello-world"
  ports:
    - name: "http"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

for SSL

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-hello-world
  labels:
    app: hello-world
  annotations:
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/hostname: somehost.com
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/http-certificates: managed-certificate-1-wildcard-somehost.com
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/name: lb-development
    load-balancer.hetzner.cloud/protocol: https
spec: 
  ports:
  - name: https
    nodePort: 32725
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: hello-world
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Comment: Do you need to provision one Hetzner LB per deployment? I want to use one LB for more than one services, it is not free. Also why do you have a nodePort on your SSL spec?

Comment: @SteveK yes you can. But you need to create two seperate services of `type: Loadbalancer`, then it works.